# Code is not working when using inside function. why?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am creating a SQlite3 GUI interface in tkinter (ttk), but i am stuck in half way. Please see the below code

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
conn = sqlite3.connect('contact.sqlite3')
conn_cursor = conn.cursor()
res = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
tables = tuple([tbl_name[0] for tbl_name in res])

table_chooser = ttk.Combobox(root)
table_chooser['values'] = tables
table_chooser.grid(row=0, column=0)
def view_table(): 
    selected_table = 'contacts' #table_chooser.get()
    table_names = conn.execute(f'''SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('%{selected_table}%')''')
    column_header = [nam[1] for nam in table_names]
    stringvar_header = [tk.StringVar() for _ in column_header]
    alldb = conn.execute(f'''SELECT * FROM {selected_table} ''').fetchall()
    stringvar = [[tk.StringVar() for _ in alldb[0]] for _ in alldb]
    def header_entry(i):
        stringvar_header[i].set(column_header[i])
        return ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar_header[i], state="disabled").grid(row=1, column=i)

    def create_entry(i, j):
        stringvar[i][j].set(alldb[i][j])
        return ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar[i][j]).grid(row=i+2, column=j)

    h_entry = [header_entry(i) for i in range(len(column_header))]
    entry = [[create_entry(i, j) for j in range(len(alldb[0]))] for i in range(len(alldb))]
view_table()          
#ttk.Button(root,text="view",command=view_table).grid(row=0,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

the problem is that, if we run the below code we can see only empty cells of Entry widget, but if we write the contents of view_table() function directly in the code(.ie without using function ) it is working fine
and you can see all the contents of table 'contacts'. in Entry widget.
so what is happening  when using function and without function

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: How did you debug this? Did you step through it line-by-line with a debugger in an IDE? If not, definitely do that first.

Comment: Using step by step debug in python IDLE  I got an error in self.gui.interaction(message, frame)
AttributeError: '_ModuleLock' object has no attribute 'name' it is in the line in create_entry() function  " return ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=stringvar[i][j]).grid(row=i+2, column=j)" line .I changed ttk with tk now it works fine.

Comment: It may be because the `StringVar`s are garbage collected after the function returns.